# Parallel HTTP requests in ruby

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, parallel-processing, httprequest

I have an array of URLs and I wan't to open each one and fetch a specific tag.
But I want to do this in parallel.

Here is the pseudocode for what I want to do:

```
urls = [...]
tags = []
urls.each do |url|
  fetch_tag_asynchronously(url) do |tag|
    tags << tag
  end
end
wait_for_all_requests_to_finish()
```

If this could be done in a nice and safe way that would be awesome.
I could use thread but it doesn't look like arrays are thread safe in ruby.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can achieve thread-safety by using a [`Mutex`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Mutex):

```
require 'thread'  # for Mutex

urls = %w(
  http://test1.example.org/
  http://test2.example.org/
  ...
)

threads = []
tags = []
tags_mutex = Mutex.new

urls.each do |url|
  threads << Thread.new(url, tags) do |url, tags|
    tag = fetch_tag(url)
    tags_mutex.synchronize { tags << tag }
  end
end

threads.each(&:join)
```

It could however be counter-productive to use a new thread for every URL, so limiting the number of threads like this might be more performant:

```
THREAD_COUNT = 8  # tweak this number for maximum performance.

tags = []
mutex = Mutex.new

THREAD_COUNT.times.map {
  Thread.new(urls, tags) do |urls, tags|
    while url = mutex.synchronize { urls.pop }
      tag = fetch_tag(url)
      mutex.synchronize { tags << tag }
    end
  end
}.each(&:join)
```

Comment: Haha, this was the exact same solution I wrote! :)

Comment: If the bulk of the work is IO, the number of cores shouldn't really matter, should it?

Comment: @ben: That's true. Still, having too many threads and open connections at the same time can be counter-productive. Firefox uses a default of 8 connections for HTTP pipelining, I think, so I now use this as the suggested value (instead of 5).

Comment: this is so beautiful Niklas !

Comment: One more advantage of this approach is that it keeps using threads while possible, so it avoids creation/destruction overhead. And this is great!

Comment: @NiklasB: I used to write custom spiders for site analysis of HUGE sites for a company that did analytics for their customers. Before Ruby was a thing I was using Perl and ran into the problem you mention, I had 100 threads running on my Linux box and it was choking. After some testing I reduced it to 75 which was the best it could handle. Later my boss called me into his office and somewhat proudly told me my little server under my desk had the highest traffic of any machine on our network, including some big servers in our computer room. All I could say was "cool!" and went back to work. :-)

Answer (score 9):

The [Typhoeus/Hydra](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) gem combination is designed to do this very easily. It's very convenient and powerful.

Comment: @Imnl please can you elaborate more on that? any source

Comment: @OshanWisumperuma In previous experience using this gem within environments that use threads (like sidekiq) bad things happen. I also found this issue https://github.com/typhoeus/ethon/issues/131

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to ruby's GIL this should be safe, based on my reading of http://merbist.com/2011/02/22/concurrency-in-ruby-explained/ and further links.

Comment: link seems to be broken

Answer (score 0):

For a less DIY solution, you can use `Parallel.map` from the [parallel gem](https://github.com/grosser/parallel) - if your fetch code doesn't have other side effects.

```rb
tags = Parallel.map(urls, in_threads: 32) { |url| Net::HTTP.get(URI(url)) }
```

And if you do need side effects, the [concurrent_ruby gem](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby) offers threadsafe classes like `Concurrent::Array` that work just like the core classes.